# how to call multiple macros using sas autos

Tags: sas, sas-macro

hello i have generic macros for specific tasks how can I automatically call a macro & the corresponding macro is compiled and executed.. i tried running a defined macro in the log and then calling the specific macro call but its to slow, but can anybody provide another solution to automatically executing the macro when i run the required macro call... thanks in advance.

below is location off my macro-->
`F:\SAS\BI\macro`

below are my sample macro in the location-->

```
%macro rand(dsn1=,dsn2=,odsn=);
Data &dsn1;
    do i=1 to 27;
        t=rand("uniform")*40;
    do j=1 to 10;
        w=rand("uniform");
        bj=0.2;
        sigma=0;
        sigma+(t*w)+bj;
        y=1/(1+exp(-sigma));    
        output;
    end;
    end;
run;

Data &dsn2;
    set &dsn1(keep=y);
    do j=1 to 10;
        *y=y;
    do k=1 to 5;
        w2=rand("uniform");
        bk=0.3;
        sigma2=0;
        sigma2+(y*w2)+bk;
        z=1/(1+exp(-sigma2));   
        output;
    end;
    end;
run;

data &odsn;
    set &dsn1 &dsn2;
run;
%mend;
%rand(dsn1=numerics.itoh,dsn2=numerics.htoo,odsn=numerics.itoo);
```

Comment: Can you explain what's too slow? If the macro runs slowly, I'm not sure there's anything you can do, besides modify the macro to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to avoid recompiling macros saved in your folder every time you use them, you should be able to achieve this by setting `option sasautos="F:\SAS\BI\macro";`. Provided that each macro you want to use is saved in a separate .sas file with the same name as the macro, that should work.

If you are using a suitably modern version of SAS, then go with RawFocus's suggestion instead, as this preserves any existing `sasautos` settings.

```
options insert=(sasautos="F:\SAS\BI\macro");
```

This still might cause some changes in macro behaviour if you have macros with the same name in your new folder and any of your existing `sasautos` folders.

Comment: That approach will overwrite the current value of sasautos.  Use the following instead:  `options insert=(sasautos="F:\SAS\BI\macro");`

Comment: Whereabouts in the `sasautos` list is the new path inserted?

Comment: at the top / in the beginning (macros there will be called first in the precedence tree)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use autocall macros then the file should only include the macro definition and not the macro call that is on the last line of the code you posted.  Also the file name should be the macro name with the extension `.sas`.  So in this case the filename should be `rand.sas`.  If you running SAS on unix then the filename must be in all lowercase.

You just need to add the path for where the files with the macro definitions are stored to the setting for the `SASAUTOS` option.  Then you can call the macro anywhere you want in your SAS program.

```
 options sasautos=('F:\SAS\BI\macro\',sasautos);
 %rand(dsn1=numerics.itoh,dsn2=numerics.htoo,odsn=numerics.itoo);
```